# Dynamic Drop Down with UL and DIVs

Tags: html, css, css-tables

Here's my situation:

I want to make a CSS dropdown. Normally I can do this no problem with embedded `UL`s. However, I want to make a multi-column dropdown. I need the dropdowns to be of dynamic width though.

I have accomplished this with tables, but Id like to see if I could do it with `DIV`s.

My CSS for the drop down `UL`/`LI` is:

```
#nav ul {
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
list-style: none;
}

#nav ul li {
position: relative;
float:left;
margin-left:16px;
}

#nav li ul {
position: absolute;
display: none;
z-index:10;
}

#nav li:hover ul { 
display:block;
}

#nav ul li a.main {
display: block;
height:47px;
text-decoration: none;
color: #fff;
padding: 0 16px 0 16px;
line-height: 48px;
border-top: 1px solid transparent;
border-right: 1px solid transparent;
border-left: 1px solid transparent;
font-weight:bold;
}

#nav ul li a.main:hover {
background:#FFF;
color:#222222;
border-top: 1px solid #000;
border-right: 1px solid #000;
border-left: 1px solid #000;
}
```

That creates the horizontal navigation with drop downs with this HTML:

```
<ul>
 <li><a class="main">HO Scale</a>
   <ul>

   </ul>
 </li>
</ul>
```

Using a table, I can put it inside the inner `UL` and use this CSS

```
.inner{
    float:left;
    background:#FFF;
    border:1px solid #000;
    border-top:0;
    padding:12px 0 12px 12px;
}
```

By putting a `Table` with class of inner in those inner `UL`s it will work perfectly, space them out, 3 columns, all dynamic width.

I'd like to accomplish that with `DIV`s, but the problem is when I float (or don't float) the "inner" `DIV` it puts all of the links on the inside one to a line, I can't seem to make them go side by side. If I put the `DIV` OUTSIDE thee dropdown, it works just fine.

Any suggestions?

EDIT:

This is how it should look (and does with tables):

[image]

This is how it looks with `DIV`s (wrong)

[image]

Comment: Can you post the image

Comment: Edited the post to include screenshots.

Comment: Try using `display:inline-block;`

Comment: @RyanSparks Been there, done that. Doesn't work.